# Aligning 3D Nifty image volumes from multiple subjects

Tags: matlab, 3d, registration, volume

I have 3D Nifty image volumes for multiple patients and in different time intervals. Which means, each patient has number of image volumes which were scanned at different times.

I have to take some measurements in these images. 
But I have 2 concerns.
      1) When considering a single patient, patient position can be different at each time 
      2) each patient's position can be different to each other
Therefore, it will be hard to compare the measurements, if I measure them as it is.

I want to align them, so that I can take the measurements int the same plane.

I know I have to do some kind of registration to align the images.
But I don't understand a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean NIfTI rather than "Nifty"?  At any rate, it seems you would have to specify more exactly what sort of measurements you're trying to do.  Are you taking them off a 2D slice through a volume and you want to make sure the z-heights match?

Comment: Yes it is NIfTI. I have to measure the area of a ROI segmented from a 2D slice. But the area has to be measured parallel to the axial plane. That is the problem, because if patient was in a different position which the axial plane from the data volume will not be the real axial plane of the patient, then the area measurement is not correct.